# RazorPay, How can I get payment failed value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, razorpay

I was implemented RazorPay in my web application successfully. If it's payment success I can get a value from handler function. But In error that mean if payment fail, I'm not able to get error value.

```
options = {
    key: User.razorpayToken,
    amount: 100,
    order_id: result.razorpay_order_id,
    theme: {
      color: "#e85250"
    },
    handler: function(response) {}
```